# how can I remove SVN bindings from folder using GUI SVN tool

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2010, tortoisesvn

I have SVN bound folder that is copied from my colleague's machine. that folder contains svn bound hidden folders which are difficult to remove manualy. Is there a way to remove the svn bindings from folder using tortoise svn GUI tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a  small GUI program or batch file that recursively search in parent folder for .svn hidden folders and delete might be also possible for this or something similar maybe the SVN command line does.

Answer (score 4):

It might not be the GUI tool, but there is an [excellent shell command](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/24/shell-command-remove-svn-folders.aspx) that can do this.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I got the shell command from googling but I wish it had a GUI option in tortoise svn though,

Comment: We can use the Export command in the tortoise SVN context menu to remove svn bindings.

Comment: Yes, it would be good but I don't think there is. At least this command does the job, and as it integrates with windows explorer it feels like a tortoise svn add-on! :)

Comment: The export control won't help if you already have a folder structure that you need to remove from SVN control. As Jon mentions "SVN export copies your project to a new folder that's not under SVN control"

Answer (score 4):

If you `export` the working copy to the same folder, the .svn subdirectories are removed. This is not coincidence but a feature of TortoiseSvn.

Answer (score 1):

[How to unversion a working copy](http://tortoisesvn.net/unversion.html) and [Removing a working copy from version control](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-export.html#tsvn-dug-export-unversion) describe what you need.